# Parse: How to use PFFile getDataStreamInBackgroundWithBlock efficiently

Tags: ios, objective-c, stream, parse-platform, nsinputstream

I am using Parse's `getDataStreamInBackgroundWithBlock` method to download a large file and save it locally.

How can I to process the stream to store the data in a file? 
Is this possible without using `NSInputStream` delegate methods (`hasBytesAvailable` etc)?

```
[databaseFile getDataStreamInBackgroundWithBlock:
     ^(NSInputStream *stream, NSError *error) {
            // 
}];
```